# Why is my button not showing up in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm making a basic app in XCode but setting up all the components is giving me trouble, why will this button not appear in landscape mode?

[image: My Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using Autolayout is the problem here. You are setting *constants* for the distances of `bottom space` and `top space`. When the device orientation changes, this leads to undesired results, such as that the button is not on screen any more.

A better approach will be to position the views **relative to each other**. So, if you want the button to stay directly beneath the text field, you can set the `vertical space` of these two components instead of using `bottom space` for the button.

Comment: Is setting them horizontally and vertically centered ok, or will that create issues as well?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the values for the constraints in the rightmost view, you will see that then do not make sense. The distance to the bottom cannot be be EQUAL to 347 in landscape mode, that is more than the height of the screen :-)

Comment: @Physics137 from your setup it looks like setting them horizontally centered is a good idea. you have to rethink the vertical positioning of  your ui elements though, it doesnt make much sense to put them vertically centered in my opinion. as I said in the answer, try to put **vertical spaces** between the views.

Comment: Looks like setting them relative to each other and horizontally centered did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue of constraints.
Set the constraints relative to your above textfield.
You are setting 347px from bottom, which leads the button to get out from the screen.